# How to use python dataframe styling in streamlit

Tags: python, dataframe, styling, streamlit

I have styled my dataframe using the below code:

```
th_props = [
  ('font-size', '14px'),
  ('text-align', 'center'),
  ('font-weight', 'bold'),
  ('color', '#6d6d6d'),
  ('background-color', '#f7ffff')
  ]

                                    
td_props = [
  ('font-size', '12px')
  ]
                                 

styles = [
  dict(selector="th", props=th_props),
  dict(selector="td", props=td_props)
  ]

df2=outputdframe.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'}).set_table_styles(styles)
```

But it doesn't work on streamlit.
So, any idea how to style the dataframe on streamlit?

[image: Image of the dataframe]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [st.table](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.table) instead of st.dataframe. Here is some reproducible code:

```
# import packages
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Example dataframe
outputdframe = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["CS", "University", "KR", 7032], ["IE", "Bangalore", "Bengaluru", 7861], ["CS", "Bangalore", "Bengaluru", 11036]]), columns=['Branch', 'College', 'Location', 'Cutoff'])

# style
th_props = [
  ('font-size', '14px'),
  ('text-align', 'center'),
  ('font-weight', 'bold'),
  ('color', '#6d6d6d'),
  ('background-color', '#f7ffff')
  ]
                               
td_props = [
  ('font-size', '12px')
  ]
                                 
styles = [
  dict(selector="th", props=th_props),
  dict(selector="td", props=td_props)
  ]

# table
df2=outputdframe.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'}).set_table_styles(styles)
st.table(df2)
```

Output:

[image]

Let's change the font size of the values in table by the value of "td_props" to "20" in the code:

[image]

Or change the colors of the header to red `#FF0000` in "th_props" of the code like this:

[image]

So as you can see it changes the color of the headers. There are a lot of options to modify the style of your dataframe using `st.table`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the styled dataframe to Streamlit.

```
st.dataframe(df2)
```

Comment: I am not sure if this works, right?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the style (that you called it "df2") with html:

```
st.write(df2.to_html(), unsafe_allow_html=True))
```